# Error while defining routes in laravel 5

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

Routes.php

```
 <?php

Route::get('/user/register', 'RegistrationController@registerUser');

//Route::get('/index', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/', 'RegistrationController@registration');

?>
```

RegistrationController.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class RegistrationController extends controller{
    public function registration(){
        return view('index');
    }

    public function registerUser(){
        var_dump(1212);
        die;
    }
}
```

The route root("/") correctly renders my page.

However when I try "**/user/register**" => **I expected to get a dump of 1212 and blank screen.** Here is what I got.
[image]

How can I fix this problem ?

Best regards,
Manish

Comment: Please try `php artisan serve` in your project root and visit `localhost:8000/user/register`. Is this working?

Comment: Are you using virtual host in other project in the same setup?

Comment: Will it work for `localhost:85/lodgify/public/index.php/user/register` ?

Comment: No need of leading slash get('/user/register'. Make it get('user/register'

Comment: Are you using serve?

Comment: I used the artisan serve and not it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do `php artisan serve` you must be in your project folder.  **php artisan serve** meant to be used with PHP's internal web server which was introduced in PHP 5.4.

You can optionally specify the `port` with

```
php artisan serve --port=8080
```

You can optionally specify the `host`  by doing something like:

```
php artisan serve --host=local.dev
```

Here local.dev mean use your ip address like

```
php artisan serve --host=192.168.0.4
```

After running this command you can browse by doing something like :

```
http://localhost:8080/user/register
```

To get more information about the `artisan` command you can do like this

```
php artisan serve --help
```

Answer (score 2):

just use

```
 Route::get('user/register', 'RegistrationController@registerUser');
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to use laravel either on server or on localhost is to point your host root to public folder to do it in Xampp open httpd.conf file located under apache/conf folder and change the DocumentRoot to your/laravel/installation/directory/public or you may create a new virtual host here by copy and pasting the default code.

Also make sure that you have .htaccess file in the root of your laravel installation directory with following contents :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

restart apache and you can surf your laravel host by just visiting localhost:85/lodglify/user/registration